# How to stop propagation in shadow dom?

Tags: javascript, dom, firefox-addon-webextensions, shadow-dom

I am making an extension which sometimes creates a shadow dom on a page. Inside this shadow dom I have an input in which user could type something, but on some pages, like on GitHub, if user types "s" it doesn't appear on my input, instead GitHub's search field becomes focused.
I tried event.stopPropagation() but with no success

How do I prevent such behaviour?

Comment: Sounds like you're doing it in `keypress` listener. Use `keydown` instead.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thank you, keydown fixed GitHub but not other pages. But I figured it out, I stopped propagation for keydown, keyup, keypress events and use input event for my stuff. It seems to work fine

Answer (score 0):

some sites listen to one of `keyup`, `keydown`, `keypress` events so you need to prevent propagation for all of these. moreover, some sites catch events in `capture` phase, so you need to account for that too:

```js
      <input
            onKeyDown={(e) => {
              e.stopPropagation()
            }}
            onKeyUp={(e) => {
              e.stopPropagation()
            }}
            onKeyPress={(e) => {
              e.stopPropagation()
            }}
            onKeyDownCapture={(e) => {
              e.stopPropagation()
            }}
            onKeyUpCapture={(e) => {
              e.stopPropagation()
            }}
            onKeyPressCapture={(e) => {
              e.stopPropagation()
            }}
            required={true}
            style={inputStyles}
            autoFocus={true}
            id="title"
            key="title"
            name="title"
            type="text"
            value={title}
            onChange={handleTitleChange}
            placeholder="Enter Title"
          />
```